Module not found: Package path ./connectors/walletConnect
I am quite new to wagmi and viem, and wanted to start with a frontend that has a simple connect button.
Here is my config file:
import { createWeb3Modal } from "@web3modal/wagmi/react";

import { sepolia } from "wagmi/chains";
import { defaultWagmiConfig } from "@web3modal/wagmi/react/config";
import { EthereumClient } from "@web3modal/ethereum";
const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_W3C_PID;

const chains = [sepolia] as const;

const wagmiConfig = defaultWagmiConfig({
  projectId,
  chains,
  metadata: {
    description: "Generated by create next app",
    name: "",
    url: "",
    icons: [],
  },
});
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, [sepolia]);
createWeb3Modal({
  wagmiConfig,
  projectId,
});

export { wagmiConfig, ethereumClient, projectId };

Then I created a separate file for all the providers, eg. UI contexts, etc, for the future.
const Providers = ({ children }: ProvidersType) => {
  return (
    <WagmiProvider config={wagmiConfig}>
      <Web3Modal projectId={projectId} ethereumClient={ethereumClient} />
      {children}
    </WagmiProvider>
  );
};

I then went on the wrap this providers around the children, in the layout.tsx file. Finally I imported the Web3Button
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Web3Button />
    </div>
  );
}

Note: the page.tsx and Providers.tsx files are client components.
I have tried messing around with next.config.js with help from ai to help me avoid these module not found errors, and I have been able to curb all of them except this.
next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false,
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      url: require.resolve("url"),
      zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      assert: require.resolve("assert"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
      path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "process/browser": require.resolve("process/browser"),
    };
    return config;
  },
};

Can anybody please help me with why walletConnect is actually being asked as a module, whereas I have never imported it once(I'm guessing it's imported in the background by Web3Modal).
Thanks in advance!
